# minimum moves to balance an array

Tags: algorithm, adhoc

We have an array of n positive integers. An acceptable move is to increase an element by 1 and decrease one of its neighbors by 1.

The minimum and maximum value in final array should differ by at most 1. What is minimum number of moves to do that?

For example if the initial array is {5, 6, 4, 1, 10} the answer would be 5 and the final array could be {5, 5, 5, 5, 6}.

Comment: I don't have any polynomial algorithm for that.

Comment: SO isn't going to just give you the algorithm. Have you thought about the problem and figured out some intuition?

Comment: If we know the target array it will be solved in O(n); just sweep the array and move greedy. I guessed maybe there exists a dynamic solution like in a suffix of array there are k maximum values but it needs some greedy moves before.

Answer (score 2):

We can use Divide and Conquer for this problem.

We know that the final value of all the elements must be the AVERAGE of all the elements in the array. If the average is not an integer, then we can define two value - MAX and MIN, such that MAX is the ceiling of the average and MIN is the floor of the average. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

Now divide the array into 2 equal parts. [ 0 - n/2 ] and [ n/2 +1 to n-1 ]. If n is odd, the first half will be smaller, but this does not matter.

For each half, calculate the average of all the elements. This average HAS to equal either MAX or MIN. If not, this average has to be either raised or decreased as required.

Now one thing to note is that, the average of the subarray CANNOT be modified by operations involving elements only within that sub-array. So any alterations would require operations between the n/2 th and the n/2+1 th element.

Another point to note is that if one sub array has average less than required, the other sub-array has average more than required.

So an appropriate operation can be easily carried out between the 2 middle elements.

Now divide each subarray in two, and repeat the process.

[ NOTE : The repeated summing operations that are required to calculate the averages of the subarrays can be carrried out in logarithmic time for both update as well as sum operations by using an interval tree http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree ]

Comment: There is a greedy fact in your solution: you move 1s between two middle elements as little as possible.(Why?)

Comment: Because, like I said, the only way to increase/decrease the average of any subarray is to move values to/from that sub-array from/to the other sub-array. Why is this required ? Because we know that in the final array, any sub-array within that array must have average between MIN and MAX, both inclusive. Plus, I don't think an O(n) greedy solution is possible ( Mine is atleast O( n log n ), perhaps more depending on how the summing operation is implemented  )

Comment: You move as little 1s as possible between your sub-arrays, just to bring their averages into [MIN,MAX], and you perform no more moves; Is it possible moving more 1s would be helpful later? If your algorithm is correct may be removing 1-lenghted sub-arrays each time work: each time move until the value of first element and the average of the rest become into [MIN,MAX]; and it will work in O(n). What is the help of divide and conquer in your algorithm?